# Building Arduino program with NewPing.h library

Tags: c, arduino

I downloaded the `NewPing.h` library and included them in the Arduino library folder but I still getting this error:

```
N:\Arduino\avoi\avoi.ino:3:21: fatal error: NewPing.h: No such file or directory

 #include <NewPing.h>

                     ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Arduino IDE, in the top go to **Sketch** -> **Include Library** -> **Manage Libraries...**

Then search for **NewPing**, and install the only one that shows.
After that you're done you can use the header like so:

```
#include <NewPing.H>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To check the correct syntaxis go to **Arduino IDE > File > Examples and search for newping examples** (they will appear if newping library is installed) if not go to **Sketch > Include Library > Manage Libraries > Search for newping > install**